Solve for real $x,y,z$ : $x^2 + xy + y^2 = a$, $y^2 + yz + z^2 = b$, $z^2 + xz + x^2 = c$ .

Solve for complex $x,y,z$ : $x^2 + xy + y^2 = a$, $y^2 + yz + z^2 = b$, $z^2 + xz + x^2 = c$ where $a,b,c \in R$ such that $a,b,c \ge 0$ .

We've :
$x^2 + xy + y^2 = a \dots(1)$
$y^2 + yz + z^2 = b \dots(2)$
$z^2 + zx + x^2 = c \dots(3)$
Subtracting $(1)$ and $(2)$ : $(x-z)(\sum x) = a-b \dots(4)$
Similarly we get $(y-x)(\sum x) = b-c \dots(5)$ and $(z-y)(\sum x) = c-a \dots(6)$ .
I'm not getting how to proceed from here 'cause summing the three giving nothing rather summing their squares gives solutions for $\sum x^2$ and $\sum xy$ but then substituting the values for $x,y,z$ seems a very tedious method .

This question is a duplicate  of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819655 but the latter (10 years ago) received no correct answer.

@AnneBauval Let's not close this one immediately let's seek for some good approaches then u can vote to close it

I never intended to vote to close it.

You can consider $a,b,c \ge 0$. Otherwise there is no solution.

@Ash_Blanc It is not a good practice to change the original post in a significant way without leaving some kind of note... You changed from real to complex solutions, which makes a big difference.

The discriminant wrt $z$ of the degree four (again in $z$; degree two in the $a,b,c$) polynomial $f_{a,b,c}(z)$ in the grobner basis of under the elimination order trying to eliminate $x,y,z$ from your system is a multiple of $$(a-c)^4(a-b)^4\(a^2-2ab-2ac+b^2-2bc+c^2)^2(a^2-2ab-2ac+b^2+bc+c^2)^2(a^2-ab-ac+b^2-bc+c^2)^2.$$

This is not an answer. Just an illustration that, depending on the relation between $a$, $b$ and $c$ there may not be a solution. Any solution of the system is in the intersection of three "cylinders". In the graphic bellow, we see that for $a=3, b=0.2, c=1$ there is no solution. Once we fix two of the parameters, the third must be in a specific interval.
NOTE: This is somehow outdated because the OP was edited to include complex solutions.


+1 : Not your fault that the original poster subsequently altered the question.  Outdated or not, it is a very nice response.

We assume that $a\ne b\ne c\ne a$( these special cases where $a=b$ or $b=c$ or $c = a$ are relatively easy). Then we must have $x\ne y\ne z \ne x$.
From the system of equations, we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{x-y}{b-c} =\frac{y-z}{c-a} = \frac{z-x}{a-b} 
&\implies (x-y)(c-a)=(b-c)(y-z)\\
&\implies (c-a)x+(a-b)y+(b-c)z=0\\
&\implies y=-\frac{b-c}{a-b}z-\frac{c-a}{a-b}x \tag{4}
\end{align}$$
Solve $(3):x^2+zx+z^2=c$ for $x$, we obtain two solutions of $x$ in function of $z$
$$x=-\frac{1}{2}z\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4c-3z^2} \tag{5}$$
From $(4)(5)$, we have two solutions of $(x,y)$ in function of $z$:
$$\color{red}{(x,y) = \left(-\frac{1}{2}z\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4c-3z^2},\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{c-a}{a-b} -\frac{b-c}{a-b}\right)z \mp\frac{1}{2}\frac{c-a}{a-b}\sqrt{4c-3z^2} \right)} \tag{6}$$

We notice that $(x,y)$ are the linear combination of $z$ and $t:=\sqrt{4c-3z^2}$. Then, for the sake of simplicity, for each solution of $(6)$,  we denote $$\cases{x = \alpha_x z + \beta_x \sqrt{4c-3z^2} =\alpha_x z+\beta_x t \\y = \alpha_y z + \beta_y \sqrt{4c-3z^2}=\alpha_y z+\beta_y t} \tag{7}$$
where
$$\cases{\alpha_x = -\frac{1}{2}\\\alpha_y = \frac{1}{2}\frac{c-a}{a-b} -\frac{b-c}{a-b}\\\beta_x = \pm\frac{1}{2} \\\beta_y = \mp\frac{1}{2}\frac{c-a}{a-b}}$$
Replace $(7)$ to the equation $(1): x^2+xy+y^2 = a$, we obtain:
$$\begin{align}
&(1) \iff (\beta_x^2 + \beta_x\beta_y +\beta_y^2)\underbrace{t^2}_{=4c-3z^2}+2(\alpha_x+\alpha_y)(\beta_x+\beta_y)zt + (\beta_x^2 + \beta_x\beta_y +\beta_y^2)z^2 = a \\
&\iff 4(\alpha_x+\alpha_y)^2(\beta_x+\beta_y)^2 z^2(4c-3z^2)= \left(a -(\beta_x\beta_y +\beta_y^2)z^2 -(\beta_x^2 + \beta_x\beta_y +\beta_y^2)(4c-3z^2)    \right)^2 \tag{8}
\end{align}$$
$(8)$ is simply a biquadratic equation $z^4 + Az^2 + B = 0$ (where $A,B$ are functions of $(\alpha_x,\alpha_y,\beta_x,\beta_y)$ that can be determined without difficulty)  that can be solved easily: $(8)$ has $4$ roots in $\mathbb{C}$ as follows:
$$\color{red}{z = \pm \sqrt{\frac{-A \pm \sqrt{A^2 -4B}}{2}}} \tag{9}$$

Conclusion: From $(9)$ and $(6)$, we conclude that the system of equations has $8$ solutions in $\mathbb{C}$ (in some special cases, two or more solutions may colapse to one, for example when $B=0$, in these cases, the number of solutions will be less).

Remark: The problem is related to the existence of a Fermat point inside a triangle $ABC$ of sides $\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt{c}$. The point $O$ is a Fermat point if $\angle{AOB} = \angle{BOC} = \angle{AOC} = 120°$ (and the distances $(AO,BO,CO) = (x,y,z)$). If $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists at most one solution.

@RiverLi indeed, depend on the  value of $(a,b,c)$, two solutions may colapse to one (for example, the case of the equation $(9)$ when $B \to 0$). It may be possible (but difficult) to solve $B(a,b,c)=0$ for $(a,b,c)$. So, I think I should write: there are maximum $8$ solutions in $\mathbb C$.

Making $y = \lambda x, z = \eta x$ we have
$$
x^2 = \cases{
\frac{a}{(1+\lambda)^2-\lambda}\\
\frac{b}{(\lambda+\eta)^2-\lambda \eta}\\
\frac{c}{(1+\eta)^2-\eta}
}
$$
and now solve for $\{\lambda,\eta\}$
$$
\cases{
\frac{a}{(1+\lambda)^2-\lambda} = \frac{b}{(\lambda+\eta)^2-\lambda \eta}\\
\frac{a}{(1+\lambda)^2-\lambda} = \frac{c}{(1+\eta)^2-\eta}
}
$$
NOTE
Eliminating $\eta$ we get at
$$
\left(\lambda^2+\lambda+1\right) \left(a^2 (\lambda-1)^2-a (\lambda-1) (2 b \lambda+b-c (\lambda+2))+\left(\lambda^2+\lambda+1\right) (b-c)^2\right)=0
$$
As $\left(\lambda^2+\lambda+1\right) = 0$ has not real roots, we follow with
$$
\left(a^2 + (b - c)^2 + a (c-2 b)\right)\lambda^2+\left((b - c)^2 + a (b + c)-2 a^2\right)\lambda + a^2 + a (b - 2 c) + (b - c)^2=0
$$
and then
$$
\lambda = \frac{2 a^2 - (b - c)^2 - a (b + c)\pm \sqrt{3}|b-c|\sqrt{2 a (b + c) - a^2 - (b - c)^2}}{2 (a^2 + (b - c)^2 + a (c - 2 b))}
$$

are u sure it's solvable it's like 4 variables and  three equations

The equations are homogeneous...

Once you know $\lambda$ and $\eta$ you can compute easily $x$ as depicted in the first formula...
